Why was the death of Minato and Kushina shown at the end of Shippuden while the attack had been shown in the beginning of Naruto?
We know that Naruto began with some scenes from the Nine-Tails attack, but why wait until almost the end of Shippuden to show how Minato and Kushina died?

Well, "Shippuden" had to follow the manga, and in manga that's where the author put it. It is thematic with the gradual reveal of who the "Mystery Man Tobi" is. We may say that the idea of Tobi was introduced at the latest in Kakashi Gaiden (i.e. the flashback about young Kakashi published during the time skip). Whether or not the decision to make him the mastermind of Kyuubi's attack was planned from chapter 1 or retconned (and hence likewise, presumably, the whole Naruto-birth stuff), we can only ask the author.

Chronology is important here.

One other thing of note is the perspective of the story, Naruto isn't a history book told in chronological order by an all-knowing narrator, it's a story that follows Naruto starting from his graduation from the ninja academy and follows what happens to him. Information is revealed as he finds it out or people explain it. The bit about the 9 tail fox at the start is Iruka remembering the event, its also how Naruto would know it, at the time neither of them knew the 4th was his father or the circumstances around the attack, both were kept under wraps until it came up in the story

To put it simply, Naruto is structured in a way that the Kyubi (9 Tails Fox) attack has so many stories within it that the scene shown at the beginning of the anime had only one:
In the beginning of the anime, there was supposed to be the backstory of Naruto being outcast from society. While Naruto himself wasn't aware of the reason why, the story tells you upfront the reason for that. It doesn't matter that the whole "why Kyubi attacked the village" is a mystery, because that's how most stories go. At the start of the anime, Naruto being outcast was the main theme, not the mystery around Kyubi.
As for Minato and Kushina's stories, it takes much more for those characters since they have much more depth in the story of the Kyubi. That needs much more buildup for the viewer to understand. You cannot just put so much information right at the start of the story without deep understanding of who Minato is, why Kushina had the Kyubi in her at all, who Madara is and why he hates Konoha, and also why Minato and Kushina decided to put Kyubi in Naruto of all people. All that is explained for the first time only when Kushina appears to Naruto, and we have a deep understanding of who Madara is.
In shorter words, what Naruto ultimately does is give the viewer a mystery cutscene at the start of the anime, where there are tons of questions to answer, only to be answered toward the end of the story. This kind of writing motive is common in literature—to uncover the secrets and mysteries of one event as the story keeps going on. Just check Harry Potter and how Rowling treated the night Voldemort tried to kill Harry.
There's also the mere fact that most writers don't necessarily know what they will write in the future. Naruto was going for more than 10 years, and only due to popularity. Who knows if Kishimoto, when he started to write Naruto, really thought that far ahead to consider that the Kyubi attack was going to be this deep story? Lots of mangaka, when seeking materials for stories, just look for easter eggs and such in early stories to make new stories connected to them. (This doesn't necessarily eliminate what I'm saying above, but explains how manga writing progression can be.)
